# why is this code not printing the value of the ar?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

This is my assignment question -

Write a Python Program(with class concepts) to find the area of the triangle using the below
formula.
area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5
Function to take the length of the sides of a triangle from the user should be defined in the parent
class and function to calculate the area should be defined in the subclass.

My program is something like this -

```
class triangle:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class cal_area(triangle):
    s = 0
    area = 0

    def area(self, *args):
        super(cal_area, self).__init__(*args)
        s = (self.a + self.b + self.c)/2
        ar = (s * (s-self.a) * (s-self.b) * (s-self.c)) * 0.5
        print(ar)

t = cal_area(23,43,56)
print(t.area)
```

I was expecting it to print the area of the triangle. But the output is this-

```
 <bound method cal_area.area of <__main__.cal_area object at 0x0415CCB0>>
```

I am using jupyter notebook.
what should I do to get the desired output.

Comment: you forgot parenthesis in `print(t.area())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`area` is a method, and you didn't call it. Add parentheses to the call line:

```
print(t.area())
```

You need to remove the `super(cal_area, self).__init__(*args)` line in `area` though (and probably the `*args` argument); your instance is already initialized, and trying to reinitialize it with new values (that may be the wrong number of arguments, as in this case) is going to cause problems.

Lastly, `area` should return the value it computes, not print it, changing the last line of the method to:

```
return ar
```